# git push in the open PR when local branch of it deleted

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I've created a pull request in the upstream with a branch named eg. `testbranch`

Now, Unfortunately, my whole `git` folder from local gets deleted.

I've created a new `git` on my local where I can see only `master` when I do `git branch`

I see that I need to push some commits to the open PR. But as the local branch is deleted, How can I do this? Is there any way that origin branch gets recreated on my local terminal and I can push the commits to the PR ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These steps helped me to push to the original Open PR

```
git checkout upstream/master -b new_branch 
(I gave the same branch name I used for the PR)

git pull origin branch_name (where I've created a PR).
```

-- make the changes --

```
git pull --rebase upstream master // rebase your branch to avoid merge conflicts

git commit -a -m "message" // commit your work
git push origin current_branch // push the changes to the github
```

New changes were successfully added as a new commits of the existing PR

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you need to clone that repository.

Then you just have to checkout the remote branch locally, make changes, commit and the push to the remote branch.

after cloning the remote branch, assuming the remote is added as origin, do -

```
git checkout -b feature_branch --track origin/feature_branch
```

Then make the changes, commit and then `git push` should add the new commit to the remote branch

Comment: I've done `git pull origin branch_name` and the changes of the Open PR is merged in my local branch

Comment: and its showing only the changes I've done upon that in `git diff`

Comment: That would merge the changes on the local branch you are currently on. Another way to proceed - just add the new changes/commits you want to make to this local branch (The branch name you get when you do `git branch`). then to push on the remote branch do `git push origin local_branch:feature_branch`

Comment: Yes, you need to get the changes locally (all the commits of the PR), then add you changes (by making new commits) and `git push` them as discussed above